# Merge Lines in Bash from Command line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Any idea how I reach this output to CSV like format in Linux bash?

Input:

```
app1
version
1
app2
version
1
version
2
version
3
```

Output:

```
app1,1
app2,1
app2,2
app2,3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, request you to please use Stack overflow's great search functionality and you will get lot of similar kind of questions, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}$1~"app"{a=$1;next}$1~/^[0-9]$/{print a,$1}' yourfile
```

This will

1. Before processing the file, set the Output Field Separator to a comma: `BEGIN{OFS=","}`
2. Then, testing if each record has the word `app`, if so it sets variable `a` to that value and skips to the next record: `$1~"app"{a=$1;next}`
3. Tests if the record contains a number, if so it prints the stored variable value in `a` and the record: `$1~/^[0-9]$/{print a,$1}`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked perfectly fine..

I amended it for another input which includes date as well in format: 2019-10-30T12:37:58.507Z
Also, changed the version check (removed $) as it was checking only for single digit version number. 

awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}$1~"[a-z]"{a=$1;next}$1~/Z$/{b=$1;next}$1~/^[0-9]/{print a,b,$1}'

Comment: That's a great addition! `awk` is fantastic at this kind of stuff. I'm glad it's doing the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/app/h;//d;/version/n;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2,\1/p' file
```

If a line contains `app`, make a copy and then delete the current line. If the current line contains `version` fetch the next line, append the copied line and swap the values of the current line and the copied line, replacing the newline by `,` printing the result.